# How to arrange the menu buttons HTML

Tags: html, css

There are 5 buttons for the site menu. They must be arranged so that the four buttons are in two rows of two, and one on top of these buttons.

```css
.button__group {
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 15px;
  top: 65%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
}
.header .button__group .button__group__link {
  width: 250px; 
}
.header .button__group .button__group__link:nth-child(1) {
  left: 0; 
}
.header .button__group .button__group__link:nth-child(2) {
  left: 50%; 
}
.header .button__group .button__group__link:nth-child(3) {
  left: 0; 
}
.header .button__group .button__group__link:nth-child(4) {
  left: 50%; 
}
```

```html
<div class="button__group">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="button__group__link">
      <a href="#">Job Offer</a>
    </div>
    <div class="button__group__link">
      <a href="#">Clients</a>
    </div>
    <div class="button__group__link">
      <a href="#">Shop</a>
    </div>
    <div class="button__group__link">
      <a href="#">Contact us</a>
    </div>
    <div class="button__group__link">
      <a href="#">Life chat</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The live chat button should be in the middle of the block. As picture
[BTN layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qp7Xr.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used `:first-of-type` to make the first link wrapper full width and after that they are in 2 columns with width 48%

```css
.button__group {
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 15px;
  top: 65%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
}

.d-flex {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: space-between;
}

.button__group__link {
  width: 48%;
  display: flex;
}


.button__group__link a {
  margin: auto;
}
.button__group__link:first-of-type {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="button__group">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="button__group__link">
      <a href="#">Job Offer</a>
    </div>
    <div class="button__group__link">
      <a href="#">Clients</a>
    </div>
    <div class="button__group__link">
      <a href="#">Shop</a>
    </div>
    <div class="button__group__link">
      <a href="#">Contact us</a>
    </div>
    <div class="button__group__link">
      <a href="#">Life chat</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to center the button `Job Offer`:

```css
.button__group {
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 15px;
  top: 65%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
}

.d-flex {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: space-between;
}

.button__group__link {
  width: 48%;
  display: flex;
}


.button__group__link a {
  margin: auto;
}
.button__group__link:first-of-type {
  width: 100%;
  align-self: center;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="button__group">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="button__group__link">
      <a href="#">Job Offer</a>
    </div>
    <div class="button__group__link">
      <a href="#">Clients</a>
    </div>
    <div class="button__group__link">
      <a href="#">Shop</a>
    </div>
    <div class="button__group__link">
      <a href="#">Contact us</a>
    </div>
    <div class="button__group__link">
      <a href="#">Life chat</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```